# Always receive null data when inserting to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4. I make it in partial view because in one form I want to insert a lot of data to other database in one time. But when I insert the data, it successfully inserts but the data that I take from textbox is always empty, only data that has been initialized can be inserted. It can be inserted successfully but the data is always empty.

Model

```
namespace admission.Models
{
    public class AlamatRumahModel
    {
        public int id_alamat_rumah { get; set; }
        public string alamat_lengkap { get; set; }
        public string provinsi { get; set; }
        public string kota { get; set; }
        public string kode_pos { get; set; }
        public string telepon_rumah { get; set; }
        public string hp { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime modified { get; set; }
        public string modifiedBy { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IRumah(AlamatRumahModel model)
        {
            Tbl_Alamat_Rumah rumah = new Tbl_Alamat_Rumah();
            model = new AlamatRumahModel();
            using (pmbEntities db = new pmbEntities())
            {
               
                int LastRumah = db.Tbl_Alamat_Rumah.Max(r => r.id_alamat_rumah);


                rumah.id_alamat_rumah = LastRumah+ 1;
                rumah.alamat_lengkap = model.alamat_lengkap;
                rumah.provinsi= Request["propinsiR"];
                rumah.kota = Request["kotaR"];
                rumah.kode_pos = model.kode_pos;
                rumah.telepon_rumah = model.telepon_rumah;
                rumah.hp = model.hp;
                rumah.fax = model.fax;
                rumah.email = model.email;
                rumah.created = DateTime.Now;
                rumah.modified = DateTime.Now;
                rumah.createdBy = "";
                rumah.modifiedBy = "";

                db.Tbl_Alamat_Rumah.Add(rumah);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return View();

            }

        }


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InsertDataDiri(DataDiriModel model, AlamatRumahModel rumah, AlamatSuratModel surat, CpModel cp)
        {
            IDataDiri(model);
            IRumah(rumah);
            ISurat(surat);
            IcP(cp);
            return RedirectToAction("InsertRiwayatPendidikan", "User");

        }
```

View

```
@model admission.Models.AlamatRumahModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("IRumah", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br><br>
                <legend>
                    <h3><span>Alamat Rumah<i class="arrow-down"></i></span></h3>
                </legend>
                <br>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Alamat Lengkap</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.alamat_lengkap, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @autocomplete = "off"})

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br />
                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="stack_id">Propinsi</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                    .Name("propinsiR")
                                    .OptionLabel("Please select Branch ...")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                    .DataTextField("Text")
                                    .DataValueField("Value")
                                    .Filter("contains").DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => read.Action("GetProvinsiByJSON", "Lokasi")); })
                            )
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="stack_id">Kota</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                    .Name("kotaR")
                                    .OptionLabel("Please select Branch ...")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                    .DataTextField("Text")
                                    .DataValueField("Value")
                                    .Filter("contains").DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => read.Action("GetKotaByJSON", "Lokasi")); })
                            )
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cmpny">Kode Pos</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.kode_pos, "", new { @class = "form-control input-md", @autocomplete = "off" })

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
```

This is what I get in my db:

[image]

Comment: "but the data always empty" - what data is empty? what are you seeing, where? please be specific

Comment: in database null inserted @MarcGravell

Comment: For *what value* is null inserted? I see no nulls in your screenshot (although I do see some empty strings)

Comment: sorry i mean empty string, in every field that i take directly to model in  view . . @MarcGravell

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed in your controller that you are instantiating the model again.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IRumah(AlamatRumahModel model)
{
    Tbl_Alamat_Rumah rumah = new Tbl_Alamat_Rumah();
    model = new AlamatRumahModel();  //Remove this line of code
    using (pmbEntities db = new pmbEntities())
    {
        ...
```

That's why you lost the values of your model. Remove that line of code, and it should work fine.

Comment: Can  you show us the implementation of the method `db.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: i'm using entity data model so i just called the entitiy

pmbentities db =new pmbentities();

that's how i get db.

Comment: I can't find anything strange with your code. Try to debug your code and find out if the `model` has been mapped to `rumah` correctly.

Comment: when i do debugging it, it always show null. I do really confused.

Comment: If the model is null when your controller action is invoked, check your view. Most probably, your model was not instantiated there, and no values were set to your model.

Comment: in the view, my model get data from user input.